# Download multiple MP3 files in the background in Android

Tags: java, android

LEVEL: Beginner
Language: Java
IDE: Android Studio
CASE: Downloading multiple MP3 files from multiple URL's in a row in the background.
ISSUE: download task in the loop to download all the urls.
the songs did download in the following path but aren't fully downloaded (every song is downloaded for 3 seconds/4 seconds basically very less).
don't know what's the problem, It'll be great if i can get any help

- receive mp3 url's from API
- download them using the following code. (ISSUE)
- get the path of all and store them in the Database
- fetch the path and play one by one continuously.

  ```
  private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<SongDetails, Integer, String> {
  Context context;

  public DownloadTask(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      Utilities.showProgressDialog(getActivity(), getFragmentManager());
  }

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(SongDetails... songDetails) {
      for (SongDetails songs : songDetails
      ) {
          donwloadsong(songs);
      }
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
      super.onPostExecute(s);
      Utilities.dismissProgressDialog();
  }
  }




   for (SongDetails songs : songDetails
      ) {
          downloadTask(songs);
      }


   public void downloadTask(SongDetails songs){
     HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
     try {
       URL url = new URL(songs.getUrl());
       httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
       httpURLConnection.connect();

      int fileLength = httpURLConnection.getContentLength();
           InputStream inputStream = new 
      BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
      OutputStream outputStream1;
      outputStream1 = new 
      FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/gbeduwarssongs/" + songDetails.getTitle().trim() + ".mp3");
      int count = 0;
           byte data[] = new byte[1024];
      int buffer_length;

      while ((buffer_length = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
          outputStream1.write(data, 0, count);
            count += buffer_length;
      }
      outputStream1.flush();
      outputStream1.close();
      inputStream.close();

  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Log.e("Error", "Download Error Exception " + e.getMessage());
  } finally {
      if (httpURLConnection != null)
          httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: can you post more code i mean complete actitivity code..

Comment: If you expect the download to last longer than a couple of seconds, then I'd suggest you use something other than `AsyncTask`, which is really only suitable for short off-UI-thread work. A Foreground `Service` perhaps, or maybe `DownloadManager`

Comment: Sure i'll update the code @AbdulWaheed

Comment: DownloadManager notifies the user in the notification section if am not wrong, I don't want user to know what's happening in the background @PPartisan Also i'll try with Foreground Service

Comment: DownloadManager did the work. Thankyou

Comment: DownloadManager doesn't work below Nougat. Could you tell me what could i use for lower level API's @PPartisan

Comment: [`DownloadManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) is compatible with Android Gingerbread and up

Comment: I got it yesterday, i was adding a method named setRequiresCharging(false) which needed API 24 in DownloadManager. Thank you for your revert :) @PPartisan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I offer to use [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) or [workmanager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) for it. AsyncTask has used a bad idea. It has a problem with a [memory leak](https://hub.packtpub.com/common-asynctask-issues/). 
The asyncTask use only [one thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937556/asynctask-execute-or-executeonexecutor)

[The same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877753/android-how-to-use-download-manager-class)

Answer (score 0):

Rather calling iteration inside a new thread, use iteration first and then start new thread in every iteration. I hope it will help you. I am posting code for your help.

```
for (SongDetails songs : songDetails) {
        new DownloadTask(pass your song object in constructor).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }
```

and in doInBackground call your downloading method stuff.

Comment: Tried this, but i got an Error: Cannot execute task: the task is already running. Also AsyncTask can only be executed once as i searched the error. So iterating it did not go well. @AbdulWaheed